# d3.js: Help understanding parameters to callback functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, callback, parameter-passing

I'm trying to learn d3.js and I find [Mike Bostock's bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock) very helpful, but often I get hung up on small details in his code. For instance, in his [Stacked Bar Chart bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208), he parses a CSV using `d3.csv`:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}...
```

I noticed that the anonymous callback function has a third parameter - I'm used to seeing `function(d, i) {...}`, but not `function(d, i, columns) {...}`. I've spent a decent amount of time looking through the [API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md) and googling, but I can't find ground truth on what parameters can be passed to the callback function by `d3.csv()` (or any of the other parsers, for that matter).

Could someone either:

- Direct me to where this is documented, or
- Explain the more fundamental d3 or JavaScript concept I may be missing here?

To be clear, I understand what is being passed in via the `columns` parameter, I'm just trying to understand where I could go to know that the third parameter is the array of column names and what other parameters can be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of that function is **row conversion function**, or simply row function (or, in D3 v3, accessor function). You can read about it in the API for [d3.dsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv).

The arguments it receives are well described in the API. According to it,

> If a row conversion function is specified, the specified function is invoked for each row, being passed an object representing the current row (d), the index (i) starting at zero for the first non-header row, and the **array of column names**. (emphasis mine)

So, as you can see, the function accepts 3 arguments, the *array of column names* being the third one. As any other JavaScript function, you can pass less arguments or more arguments to it (the excess is simply ignored).

Here is a demo of it. Suppose you have this CSV:

```
foo,bar,baz
12,43,23
23,65,32
12,27,17
```

The third argument will be the headers, that is, `"foo"`, `"bar"` and `"baz"`:

```js
var csv = `foo,bar,baz
12,43,23
23,65,32
12,27,17`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d, i, thirdArgument) {
  if(!i) console.log(thirdArgument)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, pay attention to this: each D3 method has its own arguments being passed. For the vast majority of D3 methods, the third argument is the node group.

Have a look at this example:

```js
var p = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(Number)
  .attr("foo", function(d,i,n){
    if(!i) console.log(n);
    return null
  });
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is a really great, in-depth answer. Thank you. A couple of follow-up comments/questions:

Comment: That is a really great, in-depth answer. Thank you. A couple of follow-up questions: 1) how do you know whether you're dealing with a row conv or a callback function. I see examples where there are just 2 arguments - if it's a row conversion function, each row should be passed in, if it's callback function, the entire data object is passed in, correct? - 2) Can you specify both a row conversion and a callback function? I'm guessing that is what's going on in this bl.ocks example. If so, I take it the row conv fn modifies the data, then the modified data gets passed into the callback function?

Comment: Please, don't ask further questions in the comments, specially when you didn't acknowledge the answer. Ask them as a question, so other people can answer.

Comment: I just realized I hadn't accepted your answer and came back to do so, which I have. Also, the instructions underneath the comment box specifically state that, "comments are used to ask for clarification..." Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: No worries. The thing is simpler than it seems: if there is just **one** function, it's always the callback function. If there are **two** functions, the first one is the row and the second one is the callback.

Comment: I have to be honest, when I saw "follow up questions" I stopped reading, since I really don't like users that make additional questions in the comments. But reading it again you are correct, those were intended for clarification.