# D3.js script upgrade from v4 to v7

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My D3.js graph works fine in v4 but not in v7.
I know I have to use the ".then" clause in v7 but I would like to understand the meaning of the function below " from :

...(d, i, columns ...)
...
to
...(return d)
...

What does it do exactly ? How can I code this function to use it in v7 ?

```
d3.csv("20230316_data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t; 
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
      instructions for the graph
}
```

Thank you.
Jean-michel, France

Comment: I have just seen this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764105/d3-js-help-understanding-parameters-to-callback-functions

Comment: I still need your help to rewrite this code into the v7.

Answer (score 1):

This was the `d3.csv` signature in D3 v4:

> d3.csv(url[[, row], callback])

Note that the square brackets mean some parameters are optional. However, pay close attention to the nesting of the brackets: if you have two parameters, they are:

```
d3.csv(url, callback)
```

If you want a row conversion function, you need three parameters:

```
d3.csv(url, row, callback)
```

And that's what you have (you are missing a parenthesis though). This is your row function:

```
function(d, i, columns) {
    for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
    d.total = t; 
    return d;
}
```

And this is your callback:

```
function(error, data) {
    //instructions for the graph
}
```

In D3 v7, the method returns a promise (so you can use it with `then()`, or even `async` and `await`), and it has this signature:

> d3.csv(input[, init][, row])

The `requestInit` can be ignored. So, your method in D3 v7 would be:

```
d3.csv("20230316_data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
    for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = 
    +d[columns[i]];
    d.total = t; 
    return d;
}).then(function(data) {
    //instructions for the graph
})
```

Comment: Thank you Gerardo. I am going to test it asap.

Comment: Thank you very much Gerardo. It works fine.
I now have to input json data from an ajax call instead of a csv file to feed my d3.js graph.